# Wicket: how do I set dynamic fileName (with timestamp) for ResourceStream download

Tags: wicket

I am trying to implement support for dynamically setting the fileName for my IResource each time I download the csv file.

I have attached my work so far below. Is this the right way to override and set custom file names for each download? There is a method setFileName that is also listed as an option. 
Can someone tell me which is recommended (setResponseHeaders or setFileName) and how best to implement? I am relatively new to wicket and am still finding my way around.

```
protected <T extends Object> IResource exportResource(String fileName,  final IDataExporter exporter, final DataTable<T, String> table)
{
final String file = fileName;
final ResourceStreamResource resource = new ResourceStreamResource()
    {
@Override
protected IResourceStream getResourceStream()
{
return new DataExportResourceStreamWriter(dataExporter,table);
}

@Override
protected void setResponseHeaders(ResourceResponse data, Attributes   attributes) {
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss";
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
String timestamp = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
String fileName = file.substring(0,   file.indexOf(".csv"))+"_"+timeStamp+".csv";
data.setFileName(fileName);
super.setResponseHeaders(data, attributes);
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation will work fine! To set the file name you can override any method that gives you access to `ResourceResponse`.